# PHP: Incorrect EPOCH time difference

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have a datetime object, and I want to find the difference in seconds between that datetime object and the current timestamp. Here's my code for implementing the same:

```
$myDate = strtotime('2015-08-24T19:30');
$now = time();
$ti = $myDate - $now;
echo $ti;
```

Now, I tried running this code at 18:58 local time, and I was expecting the output to be more or less `32*60 = 1920 seconds`, since the time defined in the `$myDate` variable was 19:30, and the date was the same as today. However, `21725` was instead displayed as output.

What seems to be wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server set to some other timezone. You need to set your timezone according to INDIA

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$myDate = strtotime('2015-08-24T19:30');
$now = time();
$ti = $myDate - $now;
echo $ti;
```

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks!